# Let $G$ be a finite group and $H< G$. Show the number of elements in each $H$-coset is the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am not even sure where to start but I am thinking to prove this to choose a random elements in each coset and show that the left coset $=$ right coset. That is $gH=Hg$.

Comment: $gH = Hg$ is guaranteed only when $H$ is normal. But even if it were true, I'm not sure that "left- and right-cosets are equal" implies that "all cosets have the same size."

Comment: @Shan your title and question do not match; do you mean to show $|gH| = |Hg|$ (implied by your title), or to show $gH = Hg$ (implied by your question)? The first means they have the same *number of elements*; the second means they have the same *elements*.

Answer (score 2):

Try showing that if $y \in G$ then $h \mapsto yh$ is a is a bijection between $H$ and $yH$. Thus $H$ and $yH$ have the same number of elements. Since $y$ was arbitrary, all cosets have the same number of elements as $H$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For any $\;g\in G\;$ , show the map $\;\phi: H\to gH\;,\;\;\phi h:= gh\;$ is bijective

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $H$ is also an $H$-coset, so it's enough to show each coset has the same size as $H$. To do this, let $g_0 \in G$ and we'll aim to show $|g_0H| = |H|$.  Define a function $f:H \to g_0H$, defined by $f(h) = g_0h$.  This is well defined, so if we can show it's a bijection, then we know $|g_0H| = |H|$.  Injective: if $f(h_1) = f(h_2)$, then $g_0 h_1 = g_0 h_2$, but $G$ is a group so $g_0$ is invertible, and $h_1 = h_2$.  I'll leave surjectivity to you, so we get that $f$ is bijective, and all $H$-cosets have the same size.